# Why Default output folder is unchecked when I again open Java Build Path window?

Tags: java, eclipse

my problem exists since I pulled latest changes from Git. When I open Java Build Path window I check checkBox for using default output folder, but when I again open that window, that checkbox is unchecked.
[image]

Could someone say to me why this occurs? Why when I again open this window, my check box for output folder is unchecked even if I set him as checked last time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This setting is stored in the `.classpath` file that is also be "configured" by the Maven project builder (it seems you have a Maven project, right?).

Comment: Yes, maven project..so what should I do?

Comment: Are you using m2e in Eclipse, or using maven commands to generate/modify your Eclipse project configuration?

Comment: Also, the way you worded your question makes me think you don't completely understand what that checkbox option really does. What do you expect to get by enabling it?

Comment: I am using maven commands...I expect that when this check box is selected then I run clean install and then I can run my app..

Comment: @Atenica Could you please check if it is caused by the Maven project builder by uncheck the Maven project builder in _Project > Properties: Builders_?

Comment: @howlger No, that field is checked...

Comment: @Atenica If you uncheck this field and do the Java build path settings again, will your changed settings still reverted?

Comment: I will check now....so just to uncheck this field and again try this with output folder?